# Sending string variable from PHP back to ajax with array variable...?

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, html, sql

I would like to save a message in PHP variable and send it back with my other array variable that is already coming back.  For instance, I have some error checking that takes place inside the PHP code and would like a string variable with the specific message sent back for use in my javascript.

Here is the PHP:

```
<?php
    include('config-searchres.php');

    $term = $_POST['resid'];
    $sql = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM ap_form_8 WHERE id = '$term'"); //select first name (element_1_1) from form #8

    if ($row = mysql_fetch_array($sql)){  //if reservation number exists
        if ($row['element_11'] != 'Cancelled'){  //if reservation has not already been cancelled
            if (strtotime($row['element_3']) >= strtotime(date("Y-m-d"))){  //if reservation has not already passed date
                echo json_encode($row);
            }
            else  //Reservation already passed (old reservation)
            {
                echo 'passed';
            }
        }
        else  //Reservation already cancelled
        {
            echo 'cancelled';
        }
    }
    else  //Reservation not found
    {
        echo 'not found';
    }
    mysql_close();
?>
```

As you can see, there are 3 different messages, "passed", "cancelled", and "not found"... if one of these conditions exists, I would like to send this string back to my javascript so I can display it in a DIV.  However, I also want to send the $row data with it.

My javascript:

```
    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function(){
            resetForms('reservation');
            $('#form-reservation').submit(function(event){ 
                event.preventDefault();  //the page will no longer refresh on form submit.
                var resCheck = $(this).find('input[class="reservationid"]').val(); //now we have the reservation ID, let's perform our check.
                $.ajax({ 
                    url: 'inc/searchres.php', 
                    type: 'POST',
                    data: 'resid='+resCheck, 
                    success: function(data){  //data is all the info being returned from the php file 
                        $('#reservation-id').val(resCheck);  //add read ID back into text box
                        var jsonData = $.parseJSON(data);  //parse returned JSON data so we can use it like data.name, data.whatever 
                            //****I wanted the line just below this to display the appropriate message sent back from the PHP****
$("#res-message").html('<a>Reservation ID Located, Information is displayed below</a>');
                            $('#json-reservation').populate({personal_first_name:jsonData['element_1_1'],personal_last_name:jsonData['element_1_2'],personal_phone_1:jsonData['element_7'],personal_email:jsonData['element_2'],reservation_status:jsonData['ADD THIS CELL'], reservation_id:jsonData['id'], reservation_date:jsonData['element_3'],reservation_time:jsonData['element_4'],reservation_party:jsonData['element_5'],reservation_special_request:jsonData['element_6'],reservation_using_coupon:jsonData['element_9'],reservation_coupon_code:jsonData['element_10'],reservation_status:jsonData['element_11']});
                            $("#res-cancel-message").html('');
                    },
                    error: function(){
                        $("#res-message").html('<a>There was an error with your request</a>');
                        $("#res-cancel-message").html('');
                    }
                });
            });
        });
        </script>
```

I marked with asterisks where I populate the DIV with a static message at this time, this is the line where I would populate the message from PHP.  Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Send both in ajax. LIke 
Dont echo anything in the body of your if else, just store the message in variable, say, `$message = 'passed'`, now do this at the end of your php request page:

```
echo json_encode(array('message_js'=>$message, 'row_js' => $row));
```

This sends json array as responce so u can send as much variables in it as much u like. Just put them in an array() and convert them into json using `json_encode()`
to convert into json and pass as response. When recieved in success function of your ajax, just decode the two json variables : `message_js` and `row_js`.

You can use parsejson of jquery to get your variables then

Comment: How would I split these apart in the JS?  Currently I set the data array as:  var jsonData = $.parseJSON(data);  Since the message and the data are both stored in this array now, how would i split them apart?

Answer (score 1):

You could add that message as one of your JSON properties and then search for it appropriately.

Answer (score 1):

You can always wait a little with echoing json encoded $row. 
Add $row and you message to an array variable, which you json encode and echo out.

Not 100% sure about syntax details/dots

```
$response_array = array('message' => 'yourmessage', 'row' => $row);
echo json_encode($response_array);
```

Answer (score 0):

Just pass the appropriate  message from the server .let us suppose your message is in **message** variable:

$("#res-message").html('' + data.message +'Reservation ID Located, Information is displayed below');

Answer (score 0):

By the time you convert your row data into the $row, it is an array. You can, if you dare, simply add your message to that array before you json_encode it.

```
$row["message"] = ...
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do it this way:

```
$result = array();

if ($row = mysql_fetch_array($sql)){  //if reservation number exists
    if ($row['element_11'] != 'Cancelled'){  //if reservation has not already been cancelled
        if (strtotime($row['element_3']) >= strtotime(date("Y-m-d"))){  //if reservation has not already passed date
            $result = array('status' => 'OK', 'data' => $row);
        }
        else  //Reservation already passed (old reservation)
        {
            $result = array('status' => 'passed', 'data' => $row);
        }
    }
    else  //Reservation already cancelled
    {
        $result = array('status' => 'cancelled', 'data' => $row);
    }
}
else  //Reservation not found
{
    $result = array('status' => 'not found', 'data' => null);
}

echo json_encode($result);
```

Comment: How would I split these apart in the JS? Currently I set the data array as: var jsonData = $.parseJSON(data); Since the message and the data are both stored in this array now, how would i split them apart?